# Remove parent object in document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of card sets and each set has a array of card objects. I've created a pipeline which creates a new collection with all card. Currently it inserts the card object and not each value of the object.

Current pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"cards": {"$exists": True}}},
    {"$project":  {"cards": 1, "_id": 0} },
    {"$project": {"cards.foreignData": 0, "_id": 0}},
    {"$unwind": "$cards"},
    #{"$set": {"_id": "cards.uuid"}},
    {"$out": "cards" }
]
result = database.card_sets_source.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The current output looks like this:

```
_id: <random ID>
cards: Object
  artist: "Artist name",
  ...: "...",
  number: 1
```

My wanted output looks like this:

```
_id: <random ID>
arstist: "Arist name",
...: "...",
number: 1
```

What aggregation function am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires to replace object in root and then out to another collection,

- `$replaceRoot` to replace `cards` object in root

```
pipeline = [
    # .... your pipeline stages
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$cards" } },
    {"$out": "cards" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! Will accept it as the answer in a few minutes. Any idea why I'm getting "arrays must all be same length" as an error ond a find_one query?

Comment: i am not getting you can you show example.

Comment: Ah my error, I tried to pipe the result into a pandas dataframe. Thanks again